# Response twice when using NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using the code below to send request and reading the results via PHP file which connected to MySql. The code is working but it gives the results twice. I am using UIAlert and also its appear twice.

Her is the code:

```
// to check if the user name chosen has been registred bu some one else

    NSString *userName = self.textUserName.text;
    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/MyWebSite/PHP.php?userName=%@",userName];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest
                              requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                              queryString]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

        } else {
            NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);


            if ([responseText isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
// if the user is not registered then show the tick image
                self.userNameTickImage.hidden = NO;


            }else {

// to show alert if found user is already taken

                UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"appName", nil)
                                                                  message:NSLocalizedString(@"userNameRegisterd", nil)
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"done", nil)
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [message show];

// to return nill value to the user name text
                self.textUserName.text = @"";

            }

            NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
            responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];

        }
    }];
```

And her is the result in Xcode:

```
2015-05-17 13:02:34.851 App[3710:141871] Response: {"1":{"userName":"admin"}}
2015-05-17 13:02:35.052 App[3710:141871] Response: {"1":{"userName":"admin"}}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't call it twice? try to add NSLog before calling `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem either. Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the completion handler and debug the invocation stack?

Comment: I did try to run the app on my real device, it works fine and it doesn't repeat the code. I think the problem was from the simulator